# Undefined control sequence when using chronosys

Tags: miktex, timeline, chronosys

Im having trouble using the chronosys package:

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}
  \startchronology[startyear=1800,stopyear=2000,height=.5ex,startdate=false,stopdate=false,arrow=false]
   \chronoevent[conversionmonth=false,datesseparation=.]{1900}{Test}

  \stopchronology
\end{document}
```

On Overleaf everything works fine, but on my computer using https://symera.de/texportable (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)) it doesnt. The error message reads:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.25)  1 SEP 2017 15:06
entering extended mode
**./Test.tex
(Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\chronosys\chronosys.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgf.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\ms\everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
))
Package: pgf 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.15)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count87
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen107
\pgf@y=\dimen108
\pgf@xa=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@xb=\dimen111
\pgf@yb=\dimen112
\pgf@xc=\dimen113
\pgf@yc=\dimen114
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count88
\c@pgf@countb=\count89
\c@pgf@countc=\count90
\c@pgf@countd=\count91
\t@pgf@toka=\toks19
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks20
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks21

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.35)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count92
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count93
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\systemlayer\pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen115
\pgfmath@count=\count94
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks23
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks24
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count95
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen117
\pgf@picminy=\dimen118
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen121
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen123
\pgf@xx=\dimen124
\pgf@xy=\dimen125
\pgf@yx=\dimen126
\pgf@yy=\dimen127
\pgf@zx=\dimen128
\pgf@zy=\dimen129
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2013/10/07  (rcs-revision 1.29)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen130
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen131
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen132
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen133
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2015/05/08  (rcs-revision 1.46)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count96
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen134
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen135
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen136
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen137
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen138
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen139
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count97
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15  (rcs-revision 1.18)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09  (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\basiclayer\pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
)))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21  (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen140
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen141
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\compatibility\pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgffor.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pgf\math\pgfmath.sty
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen142
\pgffor@skip=\dimen143
\pgffor@stack=\toks25
\pgffor@toks=\toks26
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\libraries\pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count98
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen144
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen145
\tikz@lasty=\dimen146
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen147
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen148
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen149
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen150
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box36
\tikztreelevel=\count99
\tikznumberofchildren=\count100
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count101
\tikz@fig@count=\count102

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\modules\pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17  (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count103
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count104
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count105
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count106

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\pgf\frontendlayer\tikz\librarie
s\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (chronosyschr.tex
\chrhelpmessage=\toks27
\chrerrormessage=\toks28
\!chrheight=\dimen151
\!chrstartyear=\count107
\!chrstopyear=\count108
\!chrwidth=\dimen152
\!chrarrowwidth=\dimen153
\!chrarrowheight=\dimen154
\!chrflechebox=\box37
\!chr!realwidth=\dimen155
\!chr!unitperyear=\dimen156
\!chrdateselevation=\dimen157
\!chrskipbefore=\dimen158
\!chrskipafter=\dimen159
\!chr!periodecolornum=\count109
\!chr!starttingtraitement=\count110
\!chr!dimentraitement=\dimen160
\!chrperiodtextdepth=\dimen161
\!chrperioddateselevation=\dimen162
\!chrperiodeventtextwidth=\dimen163
\!chrperiodbottomdepth=\dimen164
\!chrperiodtopheight=\dimen165
\!chrperiodecoloralternancetotalnum=\count111
\!chreventmarkdepth=\dimen166
\!chreventiconheight=\dimen167
\!chrstopwidth=\dimen168
\!chrgraduationcount=\count112
\!chrgraduationcount@ux=\count113
)
Package: chronosys 
) (Test.aux)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count114
\scratchdimen=\dimen169
\scratchbox=\box38
\nofMPsegments=\count115
\nofMParguments=\count116
\everyMPshowfont=\toks29
\MPscratchCnt=\count117
\MPscratchDim=\dimen170
\MPnumerator=\count118
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count119
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30
) (D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(D:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
```

The code "compiles" nonetheless with the following output:
[image]

I already included the chronosyschr.tex.

It seams like there is a problem with a non update package. Unfortanetely I cant auto-update them, because of a blocked internet connection.

Comment: Compiles without error on my TeXLive 2017 installation. Have you updated your miktex (both as user and admin)

Comment: Im using the portable version https://symera.de/texportable. I cant use the auto-updater, because of the blocked internet connection. It would be helpful to somehow narrow down the package(s) which could produce the error.

Comment: Put `\listfiles` at the beginning of your MWE and in your log you'll find all the packages you're using, with their version. Comparing them with the versions in CTAN you can see which one needs to be updated.

Comment: Like this? (Y:\Software\Tex\TexPortable\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX

Comment: Can you show us the complete `.log` file? Mark it up as code, not as a quotation. In an error message like that, the line breaks matter.

Comment: That log file is incomplete, are you sure you got the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the package `chronosys` is not properly installed.

You can do the following workaround:

1. Download from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronosys the zip file and
2. extract it in the same directory you have your given MWE.

Then you can compile your MWE (with a little pretty printing)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}
  \startchronology[%
    startyear=1800,
    stopyear=2000,
    height=.5ex,
    startdate=false,
    stopdate=false,
    arrow=false
  ]
  \chronoevent[%
    conversionmonth=false,
    datesseparation=.
  ]{1900}{Test}

  \stopchronology
\end{document}
```

without error or warning with the result:

[image]

It could be that it is a bug in MiKTeX, please report it to the support of MiKTeX (www.miktex.org).

Comment: Do I have to "uninstall" the package for this to work?

Comment: Still the same. Im using This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)

Comment: Im not at that PC anymore and used a PC with a non restricting internet connection to compile.